# Dynamic JSF (2.0) and primefaces - set action with arguments

Tags: forms, jsf, primefaces, javabeans, label

I'm trying to add JSF  dynamically to my page.
So far I can display: label's, textboxes, dropdown boxes, but no primefaces components.

**How can I add a primefaces component dynamically?**

If someone could shine a light through the fog and explain how this can be done, it would be greatly appreciated.

My JSF page:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewAction action="#{formBacking.beanAction}"/>
</f:metadata>
...
<h:panelGroup binding="#{formBacking.panelGroup}"/>
```

In my backing bean:

```
private HtmlPanelGroup panelGroup;

public void beanAction() {
        panelGroup = new HtmlPanelGroup();
        panelGroup.setLayout("block");
        panelGroup.setStyleClass("grid-form");

        HtmlPanelGroup line1 = new HtmlPanelGroup();
        HtmlPanelGroup line2 = new HtmlPanelGroup();
        HtmlPanelGroup line3 = new HtmlPanelGroup();

        //line1
        HtmlOutputText text1 = new HtmlOutputText();
        text1.setValue("Line 1 - HtmlOutputText");
        line1.getChildren().add(text1);
}

public HtmlPanelGroup getPanelGroup() {
    return panelGroup;
}
```

Comment: What about using `rendered` attribute of the dynamic JSF components instead of all this code Java stuff ?

Comment: What do you mean you cannot add Primefaces components? It works the exact same way as what you are doing for JSF components...

Comment: - I thought of 'rendered', but can't use it: my objects are created in the backingbean. (exaggerated) I can keep track of 100 objects, while only 2 objects come out of the backingbean.

Comment: -"exact the same way": This is useful! How do I do this? Do you have a link to an example how to add e primefaces object? I'm not so familiar with this, but want to learn and gain experience.

Comment: But everyone is wondering why you are creating the components in the backingbean, and not in the views as JSF is designed for? See the showcase http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/

Comment: - I create them in the backing bean, because customers add custom fields to their forms. This is created dynamically. I have looked at "dynaform" (primefaces extension) but this renders to a table. I need a responsive layout with <div>. So I need to create the objects that I need in the backing bean, and then send them to the pages.